# Nodejs XML-Parsing: Non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing, byte-order-mark

I want to parse XML-Data in Nodejs, but there always is the error:
Non-whitespace before first tag.

The reason for this error is, that the file I want to parse is UTF-8 encoded and it has a BOM.
Here is the code:

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');   
const fs = require('fs');
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

fs.readFile('data.xml', function(err, data){
if (err) throw err;
const dataWithoutBOM = data.toString().replace(/\uFEFF/g, '');

parseString(dataWithoutBOM, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    const docguID = result.Trans;
    let docguid;
    let partnerlist=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        const iD = docguID[i];
        docguid= iD.$.DocGUID;
        const partnerList = iD.Partner;
        for (let j = 0; j < partnerList.length; j++) {
           partnerlist.push({
                   name: partner.$.aname,
                   zipcode: partner.$.zipcode,
                   city: partner.$.city,
                   street: partner.$.street
               }
           );
        }
    }
    console.log(docguid, partnerlist);
});
});
```

I don't know why this error comes, because I am replacing the BOM with an empty string. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem so-called Byte-Order-Mark (BOM), a 3-byte “Zero width no-break space” Unicode character which Windows systems automatically prepend to UTF-8 files. When inspecting your file with a hex editor, the BOM shows up as hex EFBBBF.

To solve this issue:
please look on this,

https://www.apimock.com/blog/20121127_xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag

Comment: I have already tried this, but it didn´t work. I inspected it with a hexeditor and this is my BOM: **<fe><ff>**

Answer (score 0):

I just saved my file new and it worked. I still don´t know what I did wrong.